# How would you perform a simple operation on two adjacent elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series

I have an arbitrary list of elements:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f}
```

How would I produce:

```
returns = {(b - a) / b, (c - b) / c, (d - c) / d, (e - d) / e, (f - e) / f}
```

Comment: Try `Differences[list]/Rest[list]` ?

Comment: Or a more brute force approach of `(#[[2]] - #[[1]])/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]`

Comment: `1 - Ratios[list]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - might want to check that...

Comment: @ciao. Then `1 - 1/Ratios[list]`... =D

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
```

**1.**

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} :> 1 - a / b, Overlaps -> True]
```

[image]

**2.**

```
1 - Divide @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `BlockMap`:**

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

BlockMap[(Last@# - First@#)/Last@# &, list, 2, 1]
```

---

*Result:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `Table`:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

Table[(#[[i + 1]] - #[[i]])/#[[i + 1]], {i, Length@# - 1}] &@list
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `MovingMap`

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

MovingMap[Apply[(#2 - #1)/#2 &], list, 1]
```

> `{(-a + b)/b, (-b + c)/c, (-c + d)/d, (-d + e)/e, (-e + f)/f}`